# How to pass vector to server more compactly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server

Now I pass vector(movement vector) to server like this(for example):

```
[3, 4]
```

For example combinations of pressed keys I pass there by means of bit mask.

I wounder if someone could know if there is better more compact way to pass vector info to server in order to save some memory.
Perhaps there could be used least common multiple or least common denominator.
Thanks.